# Сравнить ID двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Нужно сравнить ID двух таблиц вывести только те ID которых нет в таблице #2.
Таблица 1: `product`
Таблица 2: `product_to_category`

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id WHERE p2c.category_id='125'";
```

Сейчас выводится только те ID которые есть в таблице #2. Нужно сделать наоборот.

Если так:

```
SELECT p.product_id
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c 
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
  ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
```

то выводится все id из 2-х таблиц. А когда добавляем условие `WHERE p2c.category_id='125'` то выводятся те id у которых category_id = 125. Но именно эти id мне и не нужны, а нужны id из таблицы `product` за исключением тех те id у которых category_id = 125 в таблице `product_to_category`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести нужные ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct(p.product_id)
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
  WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (
    SELECT p2c.product_id 
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c
    WHERE p2c.category_id = '125'"
  );
```

Comment: поменял местами таблицы и добавил условие

Comment: к сожалению, не то, пустой массив получается.

Comment: Если так: `SELECT p.product_id
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c 
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
  ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id` то выводится все id из 2-х таблиц, правильно? А когда добавляем условие `WHERE p2c.category_id='125'` то выводятся те id у которых category_id = 125. Но именно эти id мне и не нужны, а нужны id из таблицы product за исключением тех id у которых category_id = 125 в таблице product_to_category.

Comment: У вас в таблицах нет поля с именем "id", есть product_id и  category_id, я так понял что вы хотите получить product_id за исключением тех product_id которые есть в категории = 125 ?

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, не ID, а product_id. Вы все правильно поняли.

Comment: тогда поправил запрос выше, мне кажется тут нечего усложнять

Comment: Так уже пробовал, выводятся product_id обоих таблиц за исключением тех у которых category_id = 125. Получается еще нужно сделать что-бы остались только product_id таблицы product.

Comment: Вы в этом уверены? Вы поменяли LEFTJOIN на INNER JOIN? как может выводится product_id из другой таблицы, если мы явно указываем в запросе из какой они таблицы - "SELECT p.product_id".

Comment: Скопировал ваш код и ничего не менял в нем. Выводит 1314 product_id, хотя товаров 671. И еще некоторые product_id повторяются, а повторяющиеся product_id есть только в таблице product_to_category.

Comment: А если изменить начало на select distinct(p.product_id)

Comment: Повторы пропали, но product_id которые есть в таблице product_to_category и category_id = 125 остались.

Comment: Ясно, это товары из нескольких категорий, тогда лучший вариант убрать join и сделать not in подзапрос. Попозже напишу, а то я в дороге)

Comment: поправил запрос выше

Comment: Ошибка: `Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
Error No: 1064
SELECT distinct(p.product_id) FROM oc_product p WHERE p.product_id NOT IN ( SELECT p2c.product_id FROM oc_product_to_category p2c WHERE p2c.category_id = '125' in /home/c/cleveroom/cleveroom-demo/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 50`

Comment: Хотя нет, все ок! Просто круглая скобка немного не там была. )";

Comment: Большое Спасибо! Очень помогли!